# Oracle: Returning multiple rows in a function

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, stored-functions

I am trying to create a function which would return multiple rows.

Following is my function and type

```
create or replace type emp_type
(
first_name varchar2(20)
, last_name varchar2(20)
, depart_name varchar2(20)
)
/
create or replace function get_employee
 (loc in number)
return emp_type
as  
   emp_record emp_type;
begin
    select a.first_name, a.last_name, b.department_name into emp_record.first_name,
emp_record.last_name,emp_record.depart_name 
   from employees a, departments b 
    where a.department_id=b.department_id and location_id=loc;

   return(emp_record);  
end;
```

And I used

```
select get_employee(5) from dual;
```

I am getting "`exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows` " error.
Later when I used `rownum<2` in the select query I got "`Reference to uninitialized composite`".

Could you please help?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: What does it mean to you to return multiple rows?  Do you want to return a collection of `emp_type` objects (I assume you omitted the `as object` from your `create or replace type` statement)?  Do you want to write a pipelined table function?  Do you want to return a `sys_refcursor`?  Something else?

Comment: Hi Justin.. I would like to return it as sys_refcursor returning more than 1 row. I now added     "as object" but still getting the error "Reference to uninitialized composite".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to return a `sys_refcursor`, there is no reason to declare the object type or to try to return an object type.  Just return a `sys_refcursor`.

```
create or replace function get_employee
  (p_loc in number)
  return sys_refcursor
as  
  l_rc sys_refcursor;
begin
  open l_rc
   for select a.first_name, a.last_name, b.department_name 
         from employees a, 
              departments b 
        where a.department_id=b.department_id 
          and location_id=p_loc;

  return l_rc; 
end;
```

Comment: Hi Justin.. yesss.. it worked.. thank you so much for your help.:)